# React JS : close all other open sub-menu when other parent menu item is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i have a sidebar menu i want to close other submenu when current is clicked : so when i click to parent menu or another submenu the last submenu must be closed.

what can i add to my code to achieve this goal can any one help me on that.
[link of sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-moore-9ze6m?file=/src/Sidebar.jsx)
sidebar.jsx

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { Link ,withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import './sidebar.css'
import logo from '../logo_radeeo.jpg'
import { useSelector,useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import {FiHome} from 'react-icons/fi';
import {CgMenuGridR} from 'react-icons/cg'
import {HiOutlineDesktopComputer} from 'react-icons/hi'
import {VscChromeClose} from 'react-icons/vsc'
import {GiHamburgerMenu} from 'react-icons/gi'
import { showorhidesidebar } from '../../actions/showorhideAction';
import {MdPerson}from 'react-icons/md'
import { isAuthenticated } from '../../auth/helpers';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { SidebarData } from './SidebarData';

import SubMenu from './SubMenu';
import Media from 'react-media'
const Sidebar = (props) => {
    // const[state,setstate]=useState(true)
    const dispatch=useDispatch();
  
    const state = useSelector((state) => state.showorhidereducers);

    
    const openNav=() =>{
        
       
          dispatch(showorhidesidebar(true))
         
            if (
              document.getElementById("mySidenav") &&
              document.getElementById("main")
            ) {
              document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "277px";
              document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "277px";
              document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.remove("active")
            }
          }
           
      
      const closeNav=() =>{
       
        
        dispatch(showorhidesidebar(false))
          if (
            document.getElementById("mySidenav") &&
            document.getElementById("main")
          ) {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "90px";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "90px";
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.add("active")
          }
       
       
      }
   const sidenavdesktop=()=>{
     return(
    <div id="mySidenav" className={`sidenav`}>
    <span className="titleapp">Gestion Stock</span>
    {state ?   <span className="closebtn" onClick={closeNav}>&times;</span> :
    <GiHamburgerMenu className="humberger"  onClick={openNav}/>}
             {SidebarData.map((item,index)=>{
        return <SubMenu item={item} key={index} state={state} props={props} />
 })}


</div>
     );
   }

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 728px)").matches) {
     
      openNav()
    } else {
     
      closeNav()
    }
  },[])
    return (
        <div>
            {isAuthenticated() ?(
            sidenavdesktop()
                           
        ):""}
        </div>
      );
    }
export default withRouter( Sidebar);
```

SubMenu.jsx

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link,withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function SubMenu({item,state,props}) {
    const [subnav, setSubnav] = useState(false);
    const showSubnav = () => setSubnav(!subnav);
    const isActive = (history, path) => {
      if (history.location.pathname === path) {
        
        return {
          background:"#172b4d",
          width: '100%'
        }
       
      } else {
        return {  
          width: '100%'
        }
       
      }
    };

    
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
            <li>
                
                <Link to={item.subNav ?"#":item.path} className="" style={isActive(props.history,item.path)}  onClick={item.subNav && showSubnav  } 
                
                >
                  <span className="icon"><i className={item.icon} ></i></span>
                  <span className="title">{item.title}</span>
                  {item.subNav &&(
                      item.subNav && subnav
                        ? item.iconOpened
                        : item.subNav
                        ? item.iconClosed
                        : null
                  )}
                </Link>
               
                {
                  subnav && 
                
                <ul className={state?"show":"showleft"}>

                
                {subnav && item.subNav && item.subNav.map((item,index)=>{
                    return(
                        <li key={index}  >
                      <Link to={item.path} style={isActive(props.history,item.path)  } onBlur={()=>setSubnav(false)}    >
                      
                      <span className="title">{item.title}</span>
                    </Link></li>
                    );
                })}
                </ul>
                }
              </li>
              
             
            </ul>
        </div> 
       
    )
}

export default withRouter(SubMenu)
```

SidebarData.jsx

```
import React from 'react';


export const SidebarData = [
  {
    title: 'Home',
    path: '/',
    icon: "fas fa-dice-d6"
  },
  {
    
    title: 'Administration',
    path: '#',
    icon: "fas fa-dice-d6",
    iconClosed: <span className="fas fa-caret-down caret"></span>,
    iconOpened: <span className="fas fa-caret-up caret"></span>,

    subNav: [
      {
        title: 'Gestion des admins',
        path: '/admin/listusers',
        icon: "fas fa-dice-d6"
      },
      {
        title: 'Gestion agents',
        path: '/admin/agents',
        icon: "fas fa-dice-d6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Categories',
    path: '/categories',
    icon: "fas fa-dice-d6"
  },
  {
    title: 'Saisie Materiels',
    path: '/addmtrl',
    icon: "fas fa-dice-d6"
  },

  {
    title: 'Affectation Materiels',
    path: '/affctmtrl',
    icon: "fas fa-dice-d6",
    iconClosed: <span className="fas fa-caret-down caret"></span>,
    iconOpened: <span className="fas fa-caret-up caret"></span>,
   
  }

];
```

sidebar.css

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  }
  
 body {
     overflow-x:hidden;
 }
 

 .sidenav {
    z-index: 123548451235 !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 277px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #011627 !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 80px;
  }
  .sidenav a:hover,a.active {
    background:#172b4d;
    width: 100%;
  }

   .sidenav ul li a span.caret{
    position: absolute;
    right: 22px;
    /* transform: translatex(-50%); */
  
    
  }
  .sidenav  ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  
  }
  .titleapp{
    left: 30px;
      top:23px;
      right:19px;
      position:fixed;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
   }
  .sidenav ul ul li a{
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #e6e6e6;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  .sidenav.active ul ul li a{
    padding-left: 20px;
  }

  .sidenav.active  ul li a span.title,
  .sidenav.active ul li a span.caret ,
  .sidenav.active .titleapp span.title,
  .sidenav.active .titleapp
  {
    display: none;
  }

  .sidenav.active  ul ul li a span.title{
    display: block;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  .sidenav ul li a span.title,
  .sidenav.active .titleapp span.title

  {
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
   .sidenav ul ul{
    position: static;
    display: block;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  .sidenav.active ul.showleft
 {
  position: fixed !important;
  display: block !important;
  left: 90px;
  transform: translateY(-40%);
 background-color:#011627 ;

  /* top: 60px; */
 }
  .sidenav .closebtn,.humberger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 30px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color:white;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

i have tried to add this property onBlur in submenu item like this

```
 <Link to={item.path} style={isActive(props.history,item.path)  } onBlur={()=>setSubnav(false)}  >
```

but it doesn't work like what i want : when i select a second item in submenu the submenu is closed i don't want that . i want to close when the parent is clicked

my question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226751/how-to-close-all-other-open-sub-menu-when-other-parent-menu-item-is-clicked) but now for react js not jquery

[link of sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-moore-9ze6m?file=/src/Sidebar.jsx)

Comment: not a great answer but using Material UI would greatly simplify your life and allow you to write a lot less code. https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#drawer

Comment: can you add a sandbox pls?

Comment: yeah i have made it for you https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-moore-9ze6m?file=/src/Sidebar.jsx

Comment: by the way you shouldn't use document.getElementById etc. in react project... it doesn't work that way, you should use state for managing this elements and by this state setup their width in css